# Use JBoss with IntelliJ for creating Grails apps

Tags: grails, jboss, intellij-idea

I want to run my grails apps from intelliJ on JBoss-5.1.0.GA installed locally on my machine. 
If somebody has any experience please share.

Thanks,

p.s. The aim is to simulate different production enivronments (development,Staging & test)

Comment: I have been able to add JBoss plugin to intelliJ, however don't understand how to deploy the war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and going throught Grails FAQ's and other sites I was able to deploy and run my Grails app on a JBoss-5.1.0.GA server installed locally on my machine. The only thing that requires confiruing is:

---

**`comment out the WarClassLoaderDeployer bean inside JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`**

---

and that should be it.

Comment: However have to manually deploy the file on the server. Will try to automate it in IntelliJ next.

Answer (score 1):

Waz
Thanks so much for the answer.. I was breaking my head for many days and hours on how to get grails working on jboss5.

I found a similar answer here.. but yours was right on the head... thanks again.
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5606?focusedCommentId=212135&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_212135